# Xcode 8 Core Data abnormality

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am trying to update my project to Swift 3 which has Core Data. I have confronted with serious error and I really don't know what is going on. My Core Data Model has following properties

```
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var count: NSNumber
@NSManaged var isDelivered: NSNumber
```

I can set any other properties but isDelivered. When I try to use

```
myobject.isDelivered = true
```

I get following error on the console.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyModel setDelivered:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000d3780'

It looks like Xcode is removing `is` part from `isDelivered` property which crashes the app. Is there anything that I can do to prevent this other than updating my model? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `myObject.isDelivered = NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true)`?

Comment: Same result.As you can see from the log, message should be sent to `isDelivered` not to `Delivered`. Something strange is going on

Comment: try to make isDelivered as boolean & optional.

Answer (score 0):

It is a BUG. It is very confusing bug. For anyone visiting this question, here is the answer I found on Apple forums.

The current version of Swift 3 beta seems to have some flaw about treating properties prefixed with "is".

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50863

**Answer from user *OOPer***

Avoid using "is" in your property name, or if you cannot, try this:

```
newWriter.setValue(true, forKey: "favorite")
```

(Update)
Try adding @objc name to the property:

```
@NSManaged @objc(isFavorite) var isFavorite: Bool
```